# for /d iterating folders not working if have a - in name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a load of folders like this in a Setup folder:

```
PN 1001-1.22 abe
PN 1001-1.12 dfe
PN 1001-1.33 fgh -
PN 1001-1.01 ijk
PN 1001-1.37 lmn
PN 1001-1.02 opq
```

And each of these folders has a subfolder called install where an executable file resides.

I want to copy the executables to the .\Setup folder.  so I use a script like this:

```
for /d %%G in (Setup\*) do (
   xcopy "%%G\Installation\*.exe" .\Setup
)
```

But the script works fine EXCEPT for the PN 1001-1.33 fgh - folder.  Must be the - on end.  I get error:

```
File not found - *.exe
```

How can I fix this?  I could even strip off the - on end if that is only way?

I am running on windows 7.

Comment: Silly question, but, are you sure you have a `.exe` file inside `Setup\PN 1001-1.33 fgh -\Installation` folder? Because seeing the code the dash should not make any difference.

Comment: @MCND - I suspect an invisible trailing space after the hyphen. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31271425/1012053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file or folder name ending with `-` should not be a problem. I suspect you have a trailing space in the bad folder name.

Windows normally disallows file or folder names that end with a space or period, but there are obscure ways to create them. Once created, they can wreak havoc because many commands cannot work with these generally illegal names.

To prove the theory, execute the following command while in your Setup folder:

```
for /d %F in ("PN 1001-1.33 fgh -*") do @echo "%F"
```

I believe you will see a result like: `"PN 1001-1.33 fgh - "`. Note the trailing space.

Some commands can work with these problem names by prefixing the full path with `\\?\`. Unfortunately, RENAME is not one of them, and MOVE will not allow you to rename the folder either.

I recommend you move all the files and folders out of the problem folder to a properly named folder and then delete the offending folder. But XCOPY and ROBOCOPY cannot work with `\\?\`, so moving the sub-folders is a bit trickier.

The following script should help, but you will have to fix the "root", "old" and "new" variables to match your specific root path and problem folder name:

```
setlocal

set "root=c:\full\path\to\your\Setup"
set "old=%root%\PN 1001-1.33 fgh - "
set "new=%root%\PN 1001-1.33 fgh"

md "%new%"
move "\\?\%old%\*" "%new%"
for /d %%F in ("\\?\%old%\*") do move "%%F" "%new%"
rd "\\?\%old%"
```

After running, the problem folder should have been effectively renamed, removing the " - " suffix.

A Microsoft article defining the rules for file and folder names can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Nice. I usually see this problem in files more or less once every year. If this is the problem here, it is the first time I see someone bitten by the ending space in a folder. *Occam's razor* was the reason for my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b /ad Setup\*') do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%h in ('dir /b "Setup\%%g\Installation\*.exe"') do (
        copy /y /b "Setup\%%g\Installation\%%h" Setup
    )
)
```

**Note**(edit1): *the first variant didn't take into account spaces in the folder names.*